# Revoking permission in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

In Oracle, if the current user tries to revoke all his permissions, what'll happen?

For example, if I'm a user(**John**) created with **WITH GRANT OPTION** - can I revoke my permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Any user with the `ADMIN OPTION` for a system privilege or role can revoke the privilege or role from any other database user or role. The revoker does not have to be the user that originally granted the privilege or role. Users with `GRANT ANY ROLE` can revoke any role.

Reference

- [Revoking System Privileges and Roles](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15423)